# Is it possible to specify the display dimensions of a directly linked .swf?

Tags: flash

Directly-linked .swf files, i.e not embedded in a web page, seem to render at 100% of the browser window size. Is it possible to specify in the .swf file itself dimensions for the .swf to display at?

Thanks all,

Richard.

Answer (score 1):

In AS2:

Add the following code at the second frame (leave the first frame blank, putting the code in the first frame might give you false values):

```
Stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
```

Then you can access the stage's width & height using:

```
var myWidth:Number = Stage.width;
var myHeight:Number = Stage.height;
```

Note that there is **no underscore** before the width and height properties.
Put your entire movie inside a single movieclip at the root and set it's relative size according to these values.

Let me know if that worked for you.
Also: See my answer about [the downside of linking directly to SWF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989/linking-directly-to-a-swf-what-are-the-downsides/109016#109016).

Answer (score 0):

The SWF will always be rendered at 100%, but if you're producing the swfs you can control the size of content within them.

Comment: OK thanks. Just to confirm: I can define content, say anchored top left, with a fixed display size, say 300px x 300px, with this content not changing size whatever the browser window size is? Also what happens if the .swf IS embedded in a page, with specified object width and height?

Comment: I believe so - I'm not 100% certain so probably best to give it a try and see

Comment: No, the swf will get scaled by default. You have to use a different stage scale mode. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, with PHP you can use the function getimagesize() which works with SWF files and return its dimensions.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Just saw that I didn't understand your question properly. My answer isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to cause the SWF to open with a given dimensions if you'll point your browser directly to the file (http://www.mysite.com/somefile.swf). By doing that you tell the browser to do whatever it's default behavior when loading this file type (which can vary between browsers and computers).

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the swf from scaling its content by choosing the [stage scale mode](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode). I think what you're looking for is `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`. Then, the swf will not scale at all and display at it's initial dimensions. The default, however, is StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL.